# What does the Angular "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" Error mean?

Tags: angular, influxdb, angular-httpclient, referrer-policy

From my app I want to reach an API. The curl request is:

```
curl --request POST   https://...    --header 'Authorization: Token ...'   --header 'Accept: application/csv'   --header 'Content-type: application/vnd.flux'   --data '...'
```

It works and returns data from an InfluxDB instance. The problem is when I try everything in Angular: I set up an proxy which redirects the requests correctly (I check this in the terminal). But in the web browser (Firefox Developer Edition) I get:

```
POSThttp://localhost:4200/api/
[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 204ms].

Status 401
Unauthorized
Version HTTP/1.1
Übertragen 350 B (55 B Größe)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

The API URL is a https address, same error happens with http. Same happens in the production app.

proxy.conf

```
{
"/api/*": {
"target": "...",
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug",
"changeOrigin": true
}
}
```

Terminal confirmation:

```
[HPM] POST /api/ -> correct url
```

Request in component:

```
apiurl = '/api/';
data = JSON.stringify('request');
headers:HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
private httpClient: HttpClient) {
this.headers.set('Authorization', 'Token token');
this.headers.set('Content-type', 'application/vnd.flux');
}

getConfig() {
return this.httpClient.request<any>('post',`${this.apiurl}`,
    {
      body: this.data,
      headers: this.headers
    }
 );
}


ngOnInit(): void {

this.getConfig()
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
 data => {
   console.log(data);
 },
 error => {
   console.log(error);
 });
  }
```

I would appreciate a look your ideas!

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default#:~:text=for%20more%20details.-,What%20does%20this%20change%20mean%3F,the%20path%20and%20query%20string.)

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for the answer!. I suppose the problem is the different port(from Angular 4200 to thge aapi 80). But what can I do in order to develop properly? I also do not use Chrome but mozilla developer for the development.  Anyway in the production aI use the same origin (domain and port). Please share your thoughts on this with me!

Comment: For a cross-origin error, you could set up a Proxy in the development setup. EDIT : Oh sorry You have already tried that

Comment: try adding this to the proxy  `"pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }` after `changeOrgin`

Comment: Thank you man! This helped me out. Actually the "Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin" was irrelevant. It was just an information which policy is active... Thanky again and all the best!

Comment: If the "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" } worked for you, I can write an answer for this and you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `"pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }`

**Change your proxy configuration from this:**

```
{
 "/api/*": {
   "target": "...",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel": "debug",
   "changeOrigin": true
 }
}
```

**To this:**

```
{
 "/api/*": {
   "target": "...",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel": "debug",
   "changeOrigin": true,
   "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }
 }
}
```